# Can't build next.js app with typescript and sass

Tags: node.js, typescript, sass, next.js

Well, I've made my first Next.js app but I'm having deployment issues. I'm not sure what exactly is causing this issue, I've had to update the node version on the server and maybe that messed something up but here's my issue. I can run "npm run build" normally on my windows computer, but it fails on the ubuntu server. It throws the following error:

```
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global
Location: pages/_app.tsx
```

So, as I understand it, it's complaining that I'm not importing css in _app.js because it doesn't understand that _app.tsx is the same thing, like the build script doesn't understand typescript? Or maybe it's some sort of issue with the sass loader?

Here's my _app.tsx:

```
import { GlobalStoreProvider } from '../mptools/Store/GlobalStoreProvider'
import en from '../util/locale/en'
import hr from '../util/locale/hr'
import { LocaleProvider } from '../util/locale/NikolicaLocaleContext'
import './style.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <LocaleProvider languages={{ hr, en }} initialLanguage="en">
            <GlobalStoreProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </GlobalStoreProvider>
        </LocaleProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

And here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "nikolica-apartments",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start -p 8881"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "next": "9.5.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.52",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.1",
        "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
        "typescript": "^4.0.3"
    }
}
```

Running the node -v node-sass -v and tsc -v commands shows that all three are installed (12.19.0, 4.14.1 and 4.0.5 respectively). I'm not sure how to debug this. I've deleted my node_modules and package-lock.json and did "npm i" again but the same issue persists.

EDIT: Also, here's the tsconfig.json:

```
{                                               
  "compilerOptions": {                          
    "target": "es5",                            
    "lib": [                                    
      "dom",                                    
      "dom.iterable",                           
      "esnext"                                  
    ],                                          
    "allowJs": true,                            
    "skipLibCheck": true,                       
    "strict": false,                            
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,   
    "noEmit": true,                             
    "esModuleInterop": true,                    
    "module": "esnext",                         
    "moduleResolution": "node",                 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                  
    "isolatedModules": true,                    
    "jsx": "preserve"                           
  },                                            
  "include": [                                  
    "next-env.d.ts",                            
    "**/*.ts",                                  
    "**/*.tsx", "mptools/Helpers/range.ts"      
  ],                                            
  "exclude": [                                  
    "node_modules"                              
  ]                                             
}
```

Comment: DId you add ```declare module "*.module.scss" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}``` to next-env.d.ts file ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it. Removing the node_modules and package.json and doing npm i again didn't help, but deleting the whole folder and pulling again from git fixed the issue. No idea what wat the issue is but... ah well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build my project after updating my `next-env.d.ts` with the lines bellow:

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
```

The lines must be exactly as are show above.

I've followed this project example:
https://github.com/jpedroschmitz/typescript-nextjs-starter